# Run 2 functions inside a master function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a beginner, sorry if my code might look a bit messy.

I'm trying to write a function to send an email to a specific email address whenever a cell in a column is equal to `send_email`. The email body needs to include data from the row with the cell equal to `send_email`.

This is my code:

```
  function warnStatusBeginDay() {
  // This function imports house data, every day, between 0am and 1am, and sends an email if the time left to answer the 'acta de observacion' is 3 or 7 days from the deadline

  //Check when to send email

  var checkValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('service_1_2_main').getRange('V2:AQ').getValues();

  for (var i in checkValues) {

    if (checkValues[i][4] === 'send_email') {
      //Send email notification

      function sendMail_7() {
      // Build email body
      var email_head = "https://i.imgur.com/aaa.jpg";
      var house_id = checkValues[i][10];
      var project = checkValues[i][7];
      var name = checkValues[i][14];
      var address = checkValues[i][19];
      var neigh = checkValues[i][21];
      var municipality = checkValues[i][17];
      var country = checkValues[i][18];
      var acta_date = Utilities.formatDate(checkValues[i][13],"GMT-0500","d MMM yyyy");
      var acta_date_limit = Utilities.formatDate(checkValues[i][12],"GMT-0500","EEE, d MMM yyyy");
      var record_id = checkValues[i][11];
      var lat = checkValues[i][8];
      var lng = checkValues[i][9];
      var imageURL = checkValues[i][20];
      var mapURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+lat+","+lng+"&zoom=15&size=300x300&maptype=hybrid&markers=color:red%7C"+lat+","+lng+"&key=myKey";
      var mapURL2 = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query="+lat+","+lng;

      var body = "<p>" +
                  "<p><img src='" + email_head + "' width='269' height='70' alt='Build Change - Sistema de notificación'></p>" + 
                  "<i>[Este es un mensaje automatizado, por favor no responda a este correo]</i>" + "<br>" + "<br>" +    
                  "La vivienda a continuación recibió una acta de observación el " + acta_date + ". El plazo limite para responder al acta vence en <b>7 días</b> desde hoy." + "<br>" + "<br>" +
                  "<b>Código ID vivienda: </b>" + house_id + "<br>" +
                  "<b>Proyecto: </b>" + project + "<br>" +
                  "<b>Nombre y apellido propietario: </b>" + name + "<br>" +
                  "<b>Fecha vencimiento acta de observación: </b>" + acta_date_limit + "<br>" + "<br>" +
                  "<b>Código ID Fulcrum: </b><a href=\"https://web.fulcrumapp.com/records/" + record_id + "\">" + record_id + "</a><br>" +
                  "<b>Latitud y longitud: </b><a href=\"" + mapURL2 + "\">" + lat + ", " + lng + "</a><br>" +
                  "<b>Barrio/Comuna/Localidad/Sector: </b>" + neigh + "<br>" +                  
                  "<b>Dirección: </b>" + address + "<br>" +
                  "<b>Municipalidad: </b>" + municipality + "<br>" +
                  "<b>País: </b>" + country + "<br>" +
                  "<p><a href='https://web.fulcrumapp.com/records/" + record_id + "' title='Open in Fulcrum'><img src='" + mapURL + "'></a>" + "     " + "<img src='" + imageURL + "' height='300 alt='Imagén fachada vivienda'></p>" +
                "</p>";

      // Send email
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: "myemail.dev@gmail.com",
          subject: house_id + " - Acta de observación en vencimiento (7 días restantes)",
          htmlBody: body
        });
      }      
      sendMail_7();            
    }
    else {
      continue;
    }  
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  for (var j in checkValues) {

    if (checkValues[j][6] === 'send_email') {
      //Send email notification

      function sendMail_3() {
      // Build email body
      var email_head = "https://i.imgur.com/aaa.jpg";
      var house_id = checkValues[j][10];
      var project = checkValues[j][7];
      var name = checkValues[j][14];
      var address = checkValues[j][19];
      var neigh = checkValues[j][21];
      var municipality = checkValues[j][17];
      var country = checkValues[j][18];
      var acta_date = Utilities.formatDate(checkValues[j][13],"GMT-0500","d MMM yyyy");
      var acta_date_limit = Utilities.formatDate(checkValues[j][12],"GMT-0500","EEE, d MMM yyyy");
      var record_id = checkValues[j][11];
      var lat = checkValues[j][8];
      var lng = checkValues[j][9];
      var imageURL = checkValues[j][20];
      var mapURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+lat+","+lng+"&zoom=15&size=300x300&maptype=hybrid&markers=color:red%7C"+lat+","+lng+"&key=myKey";
      var mapURL2 = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query="+lat+","+lng;

      var body = "<p>" +
                  "<p><img src='" + email_head + "' width='269' height='70' alt='Build Change - Sistema de notificación'></p>" + 
                  "<i>[Este es un mensaje automatizado, por favor no responda a este correo]</i>" + "<br>" + "<br>" +    
                  "La vivienda a continuación recibió una acta de observación el " + acta_date + ". El plazo limite para responder al acta vence en <b>3 días</b> desde hoy." + "<br>" + "<br>" +
                  "<b>Código ID vivienda: </b>" + house_id + "<br>" +
                  "<b>Proyecto: </b>" + project + "<br>" +
                  "<b>Nombre y apellido propietario: </b>" + name + "<br>" +
                  "<b>Fecha vencimiento acta de observación: </b>" + acta_date_limit + "<br>" + "<br>" +
                  "<b>Código ID Fulcrum: </b><a href=\"https://web.fulcrumapp.com/records/" + record_id + "\">" + record_id + "</a><br>" +
                  "<b>Latitud y longitud: </b><a href=\"" + mapURL2 + "\">" + lat + ", " + lng + "</a><br>" +
                  "<b>Barrio/Comuna/Localidad/Sector: </b>" + neigh + "<br>" +                  
                  "<b>Dirección: </b>" + address + "<br>" +
                  "<b>Municipalidad: </b>" + municipality + "<br>" +
                  "<b>País: </b>" + country + "<br>" +
                  "<p><a href='https://web.fulcrumapp.com/records/" + record_id + "' title='Open in Fulcrum'><img src='" + mapURL + "'></a>" + "     " + "<img src='" + imageURL + "' height='300 alt='Imagén fachada vivienda'></p>" +
                "</p>";

      // Send email
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: "myemail.dev@gmail.com",
          subject: house_id + " - Acta de observación en vencimiento (3 días restantes)",
          htmlBody: body
        });
      }      
      sendMail_3();
    }
    else {
      return;
    }  
  }   
}
```

Basically, I'm building an array through `get.Values` and then checking:

- which row of the fifth column in the array is equal to `send_email` (`checkValues[i][4] === 'send_email'`) and then send as many emails as the number of cells equal to `send_email` in the fifth column of the array, thanks to the function `sendMail_7`.
- which row of the sevent column in the array is equal to `send_email` (`checkValues[j][6] === 'send_email'`) and then send as many emails as the number of cells equal to `send_email` in the seventh column of the array, thanks to the function `sendMail_3`.

The function `sendMail_7` works perfectly but I can't understand way the second part of the script, starting from `for (var j in checkValues) {...` is not working.

Actually the last curly bracket of the script is highlighted in red, so I think something is wrong but I don't know what.

I also tried to place the 2 functions to send emails, `sendMail_7` and `sendMail_3`, outside of the main function `warnStatusBeginDay`. In this case the last curly bracket of the main function `warnStatusBeginDay` is green but in this way the variables defined in the email body (i.e. `var name = checkValues[i][14]` or `var municipality = checkValues[i][17]`) are not working.

I'm not sure if my explanation was clear but it's my first time with Google App Scripts/javascripts in general I'm a beginner in coding.

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot,
Stefano

Comment: Try using `let i` and `let j` instead of `var i` and `var j` in your **for** loops to avoid [closure issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake).

Comment: Just a note: if you have control of checkValues better create an array of json objects with named properties...better then hard-coded numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first j does not fulfill equation in `(checkValues[j][6] === 'send_email'`) then you go out from the loop because of `else{ return; }`